# DMCA Notice Because of an Exploit

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, dmca

A person sent a DMCA notice because my web site published its vulnerabilities.

So I wonder if this is an illegitimate claim? Do you think, I should remove the page?

Edit: I think I should add my opinion also. Publishing vulnerabilities of softwares shouldn't be target of DNCA claims, I think. Even Google do samething here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/list

Comment: This really belongs on law.stackexchange.com.l - I've flagged it and hope the moderators will move it there for you. I am not a lawyer, but the DMCA notice is off base and I expect the claim is not legitimate. It appears to assert you were breaching copyright by distributing software.  If you were not doing that you are not in breach, but even if you were, I am still not sure you in breach due to the GPL and it being a WordPress Plugin (ie you are legally entitled to distribute the plugin as it has to be under the GPL). That said there are likely actions you need to take to protect yourself...

Comment: Again, I'm not a lawyer, but you may want to dispute claim (there is, I believe, a process for doing this - and I think the instructions are included in a standard DMCA notice).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very legalistic question, and I am not a lawyer. This answer does not constitute legal advice in any way.

DMCA is intended to protect copyright holders from piracy, but there is a provision in the statute that allows for copyright holders to pursue action against anyone who aids in the circumvention of copyright protections.

> The “act” prohibition, set out in section 1201(a)(1), prohibits the
> act of circumventing a technological measure used by copyright owners
> to control access to their works (“access controls”). So, for example,
> this provision makes it unlawful to defeat the encryption system used
> on DVD movies.
> https://www.eff.org/pages/unintended-consequences-fifteen-years-under-dmca

By offering information about vulnerabilities on 3rd party websites, you are opening yourself up to these types of complaints, and you may have legal exposure for damages incurred.

The burden of proof is on the complainant. To enforce any DMCA claim, the complainant would need to file a lawsuit against you (they could do it in their jurisdiction or yours) and prove in court that their copyright was harmed by your actions.

Could that happen? Maybe. They can definitely definitely take you to court if they have the resources to do so. If you don't show up or send a lawyer, then you will lose. Remember that the case may be somewhere you don't live.

It's up you to decide how you will proceed.